# How to transform list of objects into object of lists using jq?

Tags: arrays, json, jq, transformation

Let's say I have some JSON that looks like:

```
[
    {"foo": "apple", "bar": 42},
    {"foo": "pear", "bar": 13},
    {"foo": "apple", "bar": 666}
]
```

How can I transform it into something like:

```
{
   "apple": [42, 666],
   "pear": [13],
}
```

grouping the `bar`s by the `foo`s?

So far, I've tried using `jq`'s `group_by(...)` function which gave me:

```
[
  [{"foo": "apple", "bar": 42}, {"foo": "apple", "bar": 666}],
  [{"foo": "pear", "bar": 13}]
]
```

which is a start but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and efficient solution would avoid `group_by`, the implementation of which currently entails a sorting operation:

```
reduce .[] as $x ({}; .[$x.foo] += [$x.bar])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `group_by` and do the transformation after that, i.e. form the key with `.foo` and add all the `.bar`'s

```
group_by(.foo)[] | { (.[0].foo): [.[].bar] }
```

<sup>[jqplay - demo](https://jqplay.org/s/N1cAbWMf0B)</sup>